# Convert Javafx TableView into two-dimensional array

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-tableview

I am working on a project where I create a javafx tableView that looks like so:
[JavaFX TableView - Conditions -> Modes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB9Tz.png)

I want to take all of the elements out of the table and turn them into a two-dimensional array that looks like: [[A-> C], [B->D]].

Comment: `tableView.getItems().stream().map(i -> new String[] { i.getCondition() + "->" + i.getMode() }).toArray(String[][]::new)` or something like this...

Comment: Show us the appropriate snippets.

Comment: Thank you both for your help and interest. I actually was able to answer my own question once I discovered that I had a major gap in my understanding of javafx tableViews. I realized that a javafx tableview actually contains it's own observable list that made this job much easier. I could directly access the tableView with tableView.getItems() and use the list to perform the appropriate functions.